# How to combine two different populations from two different surveys?

Tags: labor-economics, applied-econometrics

I have 2 surveys, each is representative of different populations living in the same country:

Survey 1 – Survey of Peruvians living in Peru

Survey 2- Survey of Venezuelans living in Peru.

Each survey has its own population weight. Assume that only Peruvians and Venezuelans live in Peru.
I need to create the following vars:

X= number of Peruvians living in Peru

Y = number of Venezuelans living in Peru

Z= Whole population in Peru (X+Y)

W= share of Venezuelans in total Peruvian population (Y/Z).

So far, I see the following options to calculate the above vars:

1-  Calculate X and Y using, respectively, Survey 1 and Survey 2 weights. Then, sum them up to get Z.

2-  Pool both samples and recalculate weights.  Then, calculate the above variables using the new weight. If this is the right approach, what are the criteria for the new weight?

These variables will be used in an analysis of the effect of a labor outcome of Peruvians as a result of the presence of Venezuelans in Peru, measured by W.
What is the right weight approach to calculate these variables?

Thanks !